# create a byte-like object from string so that it can be further deserialized in Python

Tags: python, string, csv, serialization

I am reading a CSV file using the python CSV module. The CSV file consists of two columns:
one is of string format and the other contains the serialized representation of a python object. I am able to read the values correctly using a CSV reader iterator but cannot generate a byte-like object from the string so that I can further deserialize it.
Here is what I have tried

```
filePath = join(getcwd(),'src','data','history.csv')
data = []
with open(filePath, mode='r') as fp:
    histCSV = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in histCSV:
        # Ignoring empty lines and header line
        if line:
            data.append(line)
    # Reading the last five entries
    for d in data[-1:-5:-1]:
        expr = d[0]
        ans = d[1] # This is a string
                   # For example "b'\x80\x04K\x06.'" for
                   # object b'\x80\x04K\x06.'
                   # I want to generate back byte-like object
                   # which can be deserialized into original
                   # python object
        # further computations
```

Does anyone know how can I do it? Many thanks in advance.